# Drawing attention to tag synonym proposals

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Yesterday I [proposed a tag synonymy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=enums&sort=info&pagesize=50) between `[enum]` and `[enums]`, but no votes so far. It might be that people don't agree the two things are the same, but it may also be that no one has seen this.

If the latter is that case, and as starting a new thread on meta for these things isn't preferable, what about notifying people with more than X upvotes in a given tag that a synonym has been proposed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what about notifying people with more than X upvotes in a given tag that a synonym has been proposed?

That's an interesting idea. We have shied away from a lot of notifications but that might be smart for just that set of users with more than (x) upvotes in a given tag.

Comment: "We have shied away from a lot of notifications".. Every single time I visit the website I get a notification (of which over 75% I don't care about), I fear what would have happened if you didn't shy away

Comment: @kop disable favorite notification in your user preferences, then :)

Comment: oh, it's been implemented? I wasn't aware of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... adding notifications for this is a big can of worms. I would like it, but then again, I'm not most people.

I don't know how many people take an active role in retagging, or pay attention to the tag synonyms (visibility is an issue, as mentioned), but I'm guessing this would *not* apply to the majority of users as this stuff falls under the general category of site moderation. (And that's okay! We just have to respect that.)

If this was implemented, I think it should go in the recent activity area on a new tab, as opposed to generating messages in the top notification bar. It should *definitely* come with an opt-out option right from the start, which would simply hide the tab and not light up the envelope at all. Out of sight, out of mind for those who don't want to see this stuff. In fact, I would put a message on the tab directly, "if you don't want to see these notifications, <instructions to turn off notifications>."

So if we do that, here's the can of worms part:

- What user criteria do we use to determine who is notified?
- Which tags generate notifications?
- Do we want to show voting activity on our own proposed synonyms?
- Should our own synonyms publicly show up in our user profile somewhere? (a bit tangential)
- Should voting be allowed directly from the new page?

And on and on.

In any event, **I support this feature as long as we can work out a simple system to start with, and make sure we don't annoy a lot of users with notifications they don't care about**.

Comment: you should know that synonyms now appear in tag autocomplete areas with a count of (s)

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem will go away with time, at present there are lot of tag synonymy being created due to a large back log.

Once more people know about tag synonymies I think it will work more like.

- You see a tag that you think is wrong
- You retag the question
- You then go to the info page for the correct tag

  - You then add the wrong tag as a synonymy
  - Or upvote the synonymy if it is already there.

So within 4 or 5 times of the wrong tag being used, the synonymy will have been created.